# How to replace a tag with dynamic element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using `Jquery 3.4.1`. I'm trying to replace the `img` tag in my html with dynamically created `div` element. But it is always getting rendered as plain text instead of html.

**HTML:**

```html
<p class="post-content">
    <img src="..." />
</p>
```

**Script:**

```js
$.each($('.post-content img'), function () {
    const imgSrc = this.src;
    this.closest('p').replaceWith(`<div class="post-image"><div class="post-image-cover" style="background-image: url(${imgSrc})"></div></div>`)
});
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

Above text html needs to be rendered as HTML element.

Please assist on where I'm wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `.html()` and not `.replaceWith()`, this will maybe solve the problem you are facing. Looks like if you do `$(this).closest('p').html()` it works

Comment: But I need to replace the `p` tag with my html. I don't want to place the element inside `p` tag.

Comment: Try with `$(this).closest('p')[0].outerHTML = '<div class`

Comment: hmm that works. Can you please explain how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$(this).` instead of `this.` - to invoke jQuery functionality and not native JS, which works differently.

```js
$.each($('.post-content img'), function() {
  const imgSrc = this.src;
  $(this).closest('p').replaceWith(`<div class="post-image"><div class="post-image-cover" style="background-image: url(${imgSrc})">Test replacement</div></div>`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="post-content">
  <img src="..." />
</p>
```